# Will git-svn send file permission changes to a SVN repository?

Tags: git, file, svn, permissions

I'm using git-svn in a svn environment. When i check out .sh files they do not get the +x flag. So i change that manually, but now git tells me the file has been modified.

My question is: If i'd stage + commit those +x changes, will git push them to the svn server when i "git svn dcommit"? This is not what i want, i just want git to 'memorize' the +x changes locally but not to try to send file permission changes to the svn repository.